# Ranking joint positions in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Below is what I have

```
  userid score 
    1       8    
    2       5    
    3       4    
    4       4    
    5      10    
    6       3
```

What I want is as below

```
userid score position
    5      10     1
    1       8     2
    2       5     3
    3       4     4
    4       4     4
    6       3     5
```

**NOTE:**

I have code where I have created below output,

```
userid score position
    5      10     1
    1       8     2
    2       5     3
    3       4     4
    4       4     4
    6       3     6
```

Code is

```
SELECT userid, score, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fschema.mytab3 u2 
WHERE 
u2.score > u1.score) + 1 AS position FROM fschema.mytab3 u1
ORDER BY position
```

I want user 6 to have `position` as `5` instead of `6`

Comment: Maybe adding an `unique` could help.

Comment: it was a `distinct`, sorry, my sql gets rusty very quickly... see my answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
SELECT userid, score, 
(SELECT COUNT(distinct u2.score) FROM fschema.mytab3 u2 
WHERE 
u2.score > u1.score) + 1 AS position FROM fschema.mytab3 u1
ORDER BY position
```

Comment: Had some problem getting this to work, the difference being I'm doing it on a derived table (that is constructed from multiple table joins)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
SELECT
  *,
  @r:=IF(@score IS NULL OR @score <> score, @r+1, @r) position, @score:=score
FROM
  fschema.mytab3,
  (SELECT @r:=0, @score:=NULL) t
ORDER BY
  score DESC, userid
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could try it using variables, which looks easier. Something like this:

```
SELECT userid, score, @rownum:=@rownum+1 as position
FROM fschema.mytab3 u1, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
ORDER BY score;
```

(Currently I'm unable to check MySql queries, please, excuse me if there is some error)