# Determine the rank of each row in a sorted table

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I have this table:

```
ID Score
1   345
2   5
3   76
4   45
5   85
6   175
7   209
```

and this is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY Score DESC
```

How do I get the rank/position of **each** row?

Comment: ^But I will be iterating on the result (there's no where statement) and not just focusing on a single row.

Comment: It means i'm not selecting a single row, i'm selecting all the rows.

Comment: If you'll be iterating on the result in some language, surely you can keep track of the rank there?  You don't need to have the database give it to you if it's ephemeral and applies only at the time you query.

Comment: its not possible without a where statement in direct query.. Witout mentioning id or score in where clause you can not get the position of that particular row..

Comment: @JimGarrison, you got me there! Thank you.

Comment: see my answer... you will get rank as what you want... Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878354/ranking-joint-positions-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a technique like @OMG Ponies linked to above like this:

```
SELECT posts.*, @row:=@row+1 as 'rank' FROM posts, (SELECT @row:=0) r ORDER BY posts.Score DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run below code, you will see new column as `Position` which is same as `Rank`

```
SELECT ID, Score, 
(SELECT COUNT(distinct u2.Score) FROM myTable u2 
WHERE 
u2.Score > u1.Score) + 1 AS position FROM myTable u1
ORDER BY position
```

Let me know if you have any questions...