# ranking in mysql dynamically

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to give the rank in mysql table , suppose there is table name test with marks 45,55,55,65,75 then 75 should have rank 1 and so on

original table

```
name  marks
tom   55
joe   56
sally 57
```

result needed

```
name  marks rank
tom   55     3
joe   56     2 
sally 57     1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to order the users by marks and then count their position. This can be done in the following way:

```
SET @rownum := 0;

SELECT @rownum := @rownum+1 AS rank, name, marks
FROM your_table 
ORDER BY marks DESC
```

[Inspriation / source](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?263260-MySQL-Get-position-of-sorted-rows&p=2139314&viewfull=1#post2139314)

Comment: select *,@rownum:=@rownum+1 from your_table,(select @rownum:=0) r order by marks DESC;  will also work if you only want to use 1 SQL command, also OP make sure to take a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

Comment: That's a nice simplification :)

Comment: Actually, if we take [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking) as a valid source of information, then I think we can agree on both ranking models being equally valid (ordinal vs dense ranking).

Comment: your example is perfect and a lot more clear, hence why I just add a commentbecause you deserve your points, just showed mine in case the OP used something that wouldn't support multiple statements, like say PHP's mysql_query(). :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
  SELECT t1.*, @r:=@r+1 rank FROM (SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY marks DESC) t1,
  (SELECT @r:=0) t2
) t
ORDER BY marks
```

Answer (score -1):

I had somewhat same question and answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878354/ranking-joint-positions-in-mysql) for the same.

Let me know if you have any queries.

For your table query would be

```
SELECT name, marks, 
(SELECT COUNT(distinct u2.marks) FROM myTable u2 
WHERE 
u2.marks > u1.marks) + 1 AS rank FROM myTable u1
ORDER BY rank DESC
```

In this query replace `myTable` with your table name.

### See [demo 1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0369/2) & [demo 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0276/1).

Also, in result, note for rank 3.

If you want rank 5 instead of 4, use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(distinct u2.marks)`.

Comment: Although it may work for you, it is very inefficient as you are recursively querying a table.  For small sets, fine, but say you have 10,000 entries to rank.  You are now summing 10,000 -- 9,999 -- 9,998 -- 9,997... down to 1.  By using MySQL Variables, the order by forces the returned set, THEN the variables are applied and just can increment (decrement) as needed.  You've gone through the table once.